# Reference external workbook with multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have this excel formula which works perfectly to lookup a value in A1 from multiple sheets provided those sheets are on the same spreadsheet. I would like to extend it so it searches from an external spreadsheet where `sheet_list` is a list of sheet names on the external spreadsheet. Please help.

```
=LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,1/COUNTIF(INDIRECT(" ' " &sheets_list&"  '!A:A"),$A1),sheets_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly this :

```
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'" & $A$1 & $B$1 & $C$1 & "'!"&B$3 & ($A4+6) ),"file closed")
```

the cells a1, b1, c1 contain the path and file name detail, so all you need is to add your path / filename before the first ampersand in your expression.

Comment: Ok I am trying to understand it, which part in the formula would represent the multiple tabs (sheet names) in each spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work in this way:

```
=LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,1/COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'[external_workbook_filename]" &sheet_names_array&"'!A:A"),$A1),sheet_names_array)
```